# given the power spectral density, how to get $\|\|_{\infty}$ norm

Tags: fourier-analysis, random-variables, random-functions

Given the power spectral density of a random signal $P(\omega)$
It is possible to estimate or compute the upper bound of the signal, i.e., the 
$\|\|_\infty$ norm?